# Can conda install source distributions?

Tags: python, setuptools, conda

Can `conda install` be used to install source-distributions (i.e. non-archived import packages that have a `setup.py`)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes and no. You can not `conda install` per se. However, as the [Conda documentation](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/pkgs.html#install-non-conda-packages) says, Conda ships with pip, so you should be able to `pip install -e .` your package. You can also install with traditional `python setup.py [install|develop]`.

Remember to activate your Conda environment before installation if you're using one instead of site packages.

Comment: Hello, is it possible to install a package using `python setup.py install` from a *.yml file used in a command like `conda env create *.yml`?

Comment: why can't we do `conda install path2setup.py`?

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned by [vaiski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40759949/4459405), you can use `pip` and/or `setup.py` to build and install the package, but this method is not ideal because packages installed with `pip` and `conda` do not respect each other's dependencies.

Thus, if the source distribution includes a `conda` build recipe ([`meta.yaml`](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/recipe.html)), then you can created the `anaconda` archive on your own machine by using the `conda-build` tool:

`$ conda build meta.yaml`

Afterwards, you will have a local `tar.gz` of the build package with meta-data that `conda` can understand. This is what you download from the internet whenever you install a package using `conda`.

Finally, you can install the package you built locally using:

`$ conda install --use-local`

Comment: Tried doing that, got a `conda_package_handling.exceptions.ArchiveCreationError: Failed to clean up compressor`. :-\