# Python conda alternative to pip -e

Tags: python, pip, conda

is there a possibilty with `conda` to install a python application locally and editable from source?

Like `pip -e .` does?

Best regards,

Tom

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can conda install source distributions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756482/can-conda-install-source-distributions)

Comment: Actually not. If I use pip it will install the dependencies from pypi and not from the conda repository. If I build a conda package and install it, it will not be editable.

Comment: The linked question answers the question "Can I use conda to install from source", the answer is "no, but you can use pip" So your question "Can I use conda to install locally and editable from source" has the same answer: "no, but you can use pip". If not then please edit your question to make it more clear why it is not answered by the linked question

Comment: Ok, got it. There is no possibility. It answers my question.